# Refreshing JTable data using JcomboBox items coming from Access Database

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable

How i refresh the JTable ?

Here is my Code.

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent evt)
    {
        String text=(String)to_Cmb2.getSelectedItem();
        try 
        {
            //  Connect to an Access Database
                Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:flightdsn");
                Statement s=con.createStatement();
            //  Read data from a table
                ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT FlightNo,City,To,Arrives,Departs FROM I_Flights_Routes WHERE To ='"+text+"' ");
                ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
                int columns = md.getColumnCount();

            //  Get column names
            for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) 
            {
                columnNames.addElement(md.getColumnName(i));
            }
            //  Get row data
            while (rs.next()) 
            {
                Vector<Object> row = new Vector<>(columns);

                for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) 
                {
                    row.addElement(rs.getObject(i));
                }

                data.addElement(row);
            }
            rs.close();
            s.close();
            con.close();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        //  Create table with database data
        JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames) 
        {
            public Class getColumnClass(int column) 
            {
                for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++) 
                {
                    Object o = getValueAt(row, column);

                    if (o != null) 
                    {
                        return o.getClass();
                    }
                }
                return Object.class;
            }
        };
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        scrollPane.setBounds(50,10,400,200);
        td.add(scrollPane);
        // td is Jpanel object
        td.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Comment: What's the error you're having?

Comment: When i select next item from JComboBox JTable dose not updated with new data,

Comment: and shows the new table behind the another table with previous data   rows and the new rows whit new data.

Comment: I want table show only new data not previous data.

Comment: I've given you the answer below.

Answer (score 3):

You're creating an entirely new JTable -- don't do that. Use the same JTable but

- modify the JTable's model if you want to add new data to existing data
- or if you want to totally replace the data in the table, create a new DefaultTableModel (or other TableModel) and set your JTable's model with it via `setModel(...).

Also, as an aside you will want to avoid using null layouts and `setBounds(...)` as this creates very inflexible GUI's that look terrible on other platforms or other resolutions and are very difficult to upgrade and manage.

Comment: how i update model for my code. Can you please help me. or you can give me code for this

Comment: @arshpreetsingh: The tutorials will show you. Please look up JTable tutorial, first hit. It will explain all.

Comment: @arshpreetsingh: also as per my answer, you'd set the JTable's model via the `setTable(...)` method. To create a DefaultTableModel, check out the DefaultTableModel API and check out the constructors that are available for it. Good luck.